# how to render ejs file to local file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I've wrote an HTML page using ejs. 
Currently when i'm running the app.js, the server is running and i can get to site using localhost. I would like to save this page locally using app.js.
I guess it's very simple thing, but I didn't find it on web.

My ejs file locate on: ... /views/index.ejs

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.ejs (it's not all the file. I don't think it's relevant)

```
 <body>
<div id="cbp-so-scroller" class="cbp-so-scroller">


<%- include partials/home.ejs %>
<%- include partials/navbar.ejs %>
<%- include partials/about.ejs %>
<%- include partials/testimoni.ejs %>
<%- include partials/experties.ejs %>
<%- include partials/gallery.ejs %>
<%- include partials/contact.ejs %>
<%- include partials/sucscribe.ejs %>
<%- include partials/footer.ejs %>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example to create a file using nodejs

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Hello World > helloworld.txt');
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) but how i'm getting the html instead the 'Hello World!'?

Comment: 'Hello world!' is the string to write in the file. When you render a EJS Template, it gives you a long string of your html. Then 'Hello World!' changes to your HTML var.

Answer (score 0):

where do you call the EJS render method?,I'm seeing you're trying to get others EJS templates from index.ejs. You've got to write a function which append to your existing html index.html file.

```
function renderIndex(){
     var home = new EJS({ url: 'partials/home.ejs' }).render();
     $( 'cbp-so-scroller' ).append( home );

}
```

It could be more optimized bit it gives u and idea to solve your problem.

Comment: my ejs working on server.
I just want to save everything to locacl file and not to run it on local server (that what app.js doing right now)

Comment: do you want to write a new file using Javascript? I'm afraid it is not possible. Because Browser client it's not allowed to write in the user local machine for security reasons. Why dont you create the file in server-side?

Comment: How could i do it on server side?

Comment: it depends on what server language you're using.. PHP, Ruby on rails, python, nodejs?

Comment: Node js file system api has all what you need: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html, and fs object is what you're looking for. I've already added an answer above with some example.

Comment: 1. I'm a bit complicated with that. nothing happend if i'm running my app.js with that code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to save the rendered page as a file (ie; download) you can do this...

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res){

    res.attachment();
    res.render('index');

});
```

Comment: indeed, but where in file i should add this line? (and where the saved file)